# Rich Text in Windows Forms application

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

I would like to update a Windows Forms application to provide the following features:

- spell checking
- limited formatting of text: bold, italics, bulleted lists

Ideally the formatted text could be accessed in a plain text way for reporting through tools that don't support the formatting, but could also be rendered as HTML for tools that support HTML tags when rendering text.

It seems to me that the WPF RichTextBox would provide this functionality. What is the best way to incorporate it? Would you suggest other alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add / create a drop-in spell checker for the Window Forms RichTextBox.

A ready to go [richtextbox](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/SpellCheckCC05152007084528AM/SpellCheckCC.aspx) custom control with spell checking. 
An app for [checking spelling](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/netspell.aspx) that could be easily integrated

Also [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPFRichTextBox09072008194855PM/WPFRichTextBox.aspx) is a article on adding a WPF RichTextBox to your application, as well as getting spell checking working. (Requires .NET 3.0+)

Answer (score 2):

I <s>haven't check yet</s> if it will work in a RichTextBox but it should... try the following attached property

```
<TextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" />
```

Read more about this [here](http://dotnet.org.za/rudi/archive/2007/11/01/spell-check-in-wpf-text-controls.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Forms has a RichTextBox also. If you're in a Windows Forms application, it will be easier to incorporate that than incorporate the WPF control.